# Combine image upload ajax with form submit ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, forms

I have image upload ajax like this

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log(file);
    var uploadUrl = "/api/upload_image";//It will also goes to '/api/get_data'
    //fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(e){
        console.log("Success");
    })
    .error(function(e){
        console.log("Error");
    });
};
```

And calling submit form ajax like this.

```
$http({
    url: "/api/get_data",
    method: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:JSON.stringify(this.formData)
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log("Success");      
}).error(function(error) {
    console.log("Error");
});
```

Both are working but separately, How to combine these two ajax into one, that is submit ajax, the second one.

Or is there any way to post image data in second ajax, I am using angular+laravel5.2

My file input in angular view is

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile">
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are two different url. So combining one with another may not be the ide. Instead you can use promise and chain multiple promise

Comment: @user2181397 I am sorry for different url , I needed it as a one url `/api/get_data`

Comment: what format are you uploading the image as? what are you trying to build? an image uploader for your site?

Comment: @AlanSutherland, I am trying to submit image with normal form data of any format of image.

Comment: ok you may need to break it down to binary first, where are you submitting it to?

Comment: to this url `/api/get_data`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine this two ajax like this, to post image and formData, Try with this.

```
var file = $scope.myFile;
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);
fd.append('formData', JSON.stringify(this.formData));


$http({
    url: "/api/get_data",
    method: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    data:fd
}).success(function(data) {
```

To retrieve `formData` you need to decode json at server side scripting.